# Rust ssh2 download using scp

Tags: windows, rust, scp, ssh2

I've spent the day trying to use [ssh2](https://crates.io/crates/ssh2) to download a file by using scp. To test this I've set up a OpenSSH server on my localhost on port 22 and created some dummy files for the program to copy from one location to another. I'm running this on Windows 10 and I've not changed anything in my ssh config file since installing the OpenSSH feature this morning.

It works when I'm doing the following in cmd:

```
scp username@localhost:c/users/username/logs/from.log c:/users/username/logs/to.log
```

But for some reason when I'm running my program it exits with the following error:

```
Error: Error { code: Session(-28), msg: "Failed to recv file" }
```

This is the code I'm trying run and at row 10 (on the call to sess.scp_recv) is where I'm getting the error:

```rust
pub fn test_download() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let conn = TcpStream::connect("localhost:22")?;
    let mut sess = ssh2::Session::new()?;
    sess.set_tcp_stream(conn);
    sess.set_timeout(5_000);
    sess.handshake()?;
    sess.userauth_password("username", "password")?;

    let (mut remote_file, _) = sess.scp_recv(Path::new(r"c:\users\username\logs\from.log"))?;
    let mut content = String::new();
    remote_file.read_to_string(&mut content)?;

    remote_file.send_eof()?;
    remote_file.wait_eof()?;
    remote_file.close()?;
    remote_file.wait_close()?;

    std::fs::write(r"c:\users\username\logs\to.log", &content)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I've been googling like a maniac and I can't find an explanation for this, so here I am. Note that I'm new to both Rust and ssh.

**Update**

I ran sshd.exe -d and connected using my program and the logging looks fine right up until the very end:

```
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: user domain\\user matched group list administrators at line 87
Accepted password for user from 127.0.0.1 port 52813 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: user has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: Not running as SYSTEM: skipping loading user profile
**CreateProcessAsUserW failed error:1314**
fork of unprivileged child failed
debug1: do_cleanup
```

So it looks like there's some sort of privilege situation going on with Windows here.

**Solved**

I finally solved this by instead of using the scp_recv function I ran *pscp -pw password -scp remote local* using the std::process::Command crate and supplying the paths and password

Comment: The most likely cause is that you mistyped the path in your `scp_recv` command. Recheck it. (If this didn't look so windows-y, I'd tell you to add a sleep before the `scp_recv`, ssh into the server, and `strace -ff -p` the sshd process.)

Comment: Unfortunately it's all very Windows-y. I tested my spelling by making the program print all of the input data as an scp command, copied and pasted it into my cmd and that worked so it shouldn't be the spelling.

Comment: Have you tried forward slashes or not adding the colon, as in your original scp shell command? Also, have you tried this on a linux machine? Last, if you're worried that the path is mangled somewhere, you can set `LogLevel DEBUG3` in the `sshd_config` and look for a `mm_audit_end_command` event, and compare that with your shell scp command.

Comment: I have tried using forward slashes and the missing colon is just me doing something wrong when I rewrote the lines to remove any personal data. I'll have a look at the log file, thank you.

Comment: And, what was the log output? Were there any `mm_audit_end_command`s?